# modify the linked list main function code in which user will input the index and data of the node with proper messages

Tags: c++

I have a link list in which user will input the index and data of the node with proper messages....

it is a very simple task i know but i am so confuse how to do it .

all i want is that you edit my code so that user can enter which index he/she want to enter data and also he/she is able to enter his/her data..

I'll be very great full if some one reply .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node {
public:
    double data; // data
    Node* next; // pointer to next
};
class List {
public:
    List(void) { head = NULL; } // constructor
    ~List(void); // destructor
    bool IsEmpty() { return head == NULL; }
    Node* InsertNode(int index, double x);
    int FindNode(double x);
    int DeleteNode(double x);
    void DisplayList(void);

private:
    Node* head;
};
Node* List::InsertNode(int index, double x)
{
    if (index < 0)
        return NULL;
    int currIndex = 1;
    Node* currNode = head;
    while (currNode && index > currIndex) {
        //Try to locate index'th node. If it doesn't exist, return NULL
        currNode = currNode->next;
        currIndex++;
    }
    if (index > 0 && currNode == NULL)
        return NULL;
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = x;
    if (index == 0) {
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        newNode->next = currNode->next;
        currNode->next = newNode;
    }
    return newNode;
}
int List::FindNode(double x)
{
    Node* currNode = head;
    int currIndex = 1;
    while (currNode && currNode->data != x) {
        currNode = currNode->next;
        currIndex++;
    }
    if (currNode)
        return currIndex;
    return 0;
}
int List::DeleteNode(double x)
{
    Node* prevNode = NULL;
    Node* currNode = head;
    int currIndex = 1;
    while (currNode && currNode->data != x) {
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = currNode->next;
        currIndex++;
    }
    if (currNode) {
        if (prevNode) {
            prevNode->next = currNode->next;
            delete currNode;
        }
        else {
            head = currNode->next;
            delete currNode;
        }
        return currIndex;
    }
    return 0;
}
void List::DisplayList()
{
    int num = 0;
    Node* currNode = head;
    while (currNode != NULL) {
        cout << currNode->data << endl;
        currNode = currNode->next;
        num++;
    }
    cout << "Number of nodes in the list: " << num << endl;
}
List::~List(void)
{
    Node* currNode = head;
    Node* nextNode = NULL;
    while (currNode != NULL) {
        nextNode = currNode->next;
        delete currNode; // destroy the current node
        currNode = nextNode;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    List list;
    list.InsertNode(0, 7.0); // successful
    list.InsertNode(1, 5.0); // successful
    list.InsertNode(-1, 5.0); // unsuccessful
    list.InsertNode(0, 6.0); // successful
    list.InsertNode(8, 4.0); // unsuccessful
    // print all the elements
    list.DisplayList();
    if (list.FindNode(5.0) > 0)
        cout << "5.0 found" << endl;
    else
        cout << "5.0 not found" << endl;
    if (list.FindNode(4.5) > 0)
        cout << "4.5 found" << endl;
    else
        cout << "4.5 not found" << endl;
    list.DeleteNode(7.0);
    list.DisplayList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to create a function that run n number of node and edit the data in the n node

Comment: Can you do it for me? please its urgent

Comment: in SOF [how to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry it a very simple task 
1:- firstly you should give values in particulate index
2:- ten just fetch it from the particular index

for further information you can contact

Answer (score 1):

Just read in the input and call the method on the list object. What did you find so confusing about it?
Also, try to get out of the habit of using namespace std! Append this code to the main function.

```
int index;
double data;
std::cout << "Enter the index: ";
std::cin >> index;
std::cout << "Enter data: ";
std::cin >> data;
list.InsertNode(index, data);
list.DisplayList();
```

Declare temporary variables `index` and `data` to hold the input from the console.
Print to the console asking the user to enter the index and data using `std::cout` , which is at the position at which the node is to be entered. `std::cin` can be used to read input from the console and store it in a variable
The nodes of your linked list contain a data field of type  `double` which is the actual data of your linked list. Using your `list` object, you call the `InsertNode()` method along with this index and data.

Comment: isn't it good to use " using namespace std " so that we have to write it once .not in every line ....?